# (Arraylist) Crashes when user defined String input

Tags: java, arraylist

The purpose of the program is to let the user input 5 numbers and select which game they would like to compare them to (lotto/lottoplus1/lottoplus2) with each having a unique set of 5 numbers, then to be stored in an arraylist.

> The national lottery run three draws on each night: Lotto, Lotto plus one and Lotto plus 2.
>
> generate numbers for each of these draws.
>
> When a user enters a line of numbers they should also enter either:"lotto", "plus1", or "plus2" to specify which of the draws their numbers should be compared to.
>
> This value should then be assigned to that specific line of numbers and the numbers on that line should be compared against each set of Lotto numbers as required.

Heres my problem! When I input my five numbers then lets say 'plus1' to assign the comparison of those numbers to lotteryPlusOne it crashes and outputs this message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at lottoapp.lottoCounter.compareNums(lottoCounter.java:136) at lottoapp.LottoApp.main(LottoApp.java:61) C:\Users\x15587907\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor‌​-snippets\run.xml:53‌​: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)

Below is line 136 it is in the Instantiable class in the public void compareNums() method
l = madeUpArrayList.get(i); <-----

Main App

---

```
package lottoapp;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LottoApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare vars/objects/arrays
    int[] lottery = new int[5];             //5 Winning numbers
    int[] lotteryPlus1 = new int[5];        //5 Winning LP1 numbers
    int[] lotteryPlus2 = new int[5];        //5 Winning LP2 numbers        
    String gameType;
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    int number4;
    int number5;

    //array list called madeUpArrayList
    ArrayList<lottoCounter> madeUpArrayList = new ArrayList();

    //object declare and create
    lottoCounter myCount = new lottoCounter();

    //winNums/getLottery need to be initialised at top of program
    myCount.winNums();
    lottery = myCount.getLottery();
    lotteryPlus1 = myCount.getLotteryPlus1();
    lotteryPlus2 = myCount.getLotteryPlus2();

    //Displays winning numbers (Testing Purposes)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lottery));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lotteryPlus1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lotteryPlus2));

    //Array List
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        lottoCounter l = new lottoCounter();
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number 1 "));
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number 2 "));
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number 3 "));
        number4 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number 4 "));
        number5 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number 5 "));
        gameType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select a game type for comparison ... lotto/plus1/plus2");

        l.setNumber1(number1);
        l.setNumber2(number2);
        l.setNumber3(number3);
        l.setNumber4(number4);
        l.setNumber5(number5);
        l.setGameType(gameType);

        madeUpArrayList.add(l);
    }

    //Comparison
    myCount.compareNums();

    //Output Lotto,Lotto Plus One and Lotto plus Two correct guesses
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guesses correct for Regular Lottery correct is " + myCount.getCorrectLotto());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guesses correct for Lottery Plus One is " + myCount.getCorrectPlusOne());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guesses correct for Lottery Plus Two is " + myCount.getCorrectPlusTwo());

}
```

}

Instantiable Class

---

```
package lottoapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class lottoCounter {

//Variables/Constants/data members
private int correctLotto;
private int correctPlusOne;
private int correctPlusTwo;
private int[] lottery = new int[5];
private int[] lotteryPlus1 = new int[5];
private int[] lotteryPlus2 = new int[5];
private int number1;
private int number2;
private int number3;
private int number4;
private int number5;
private String gameType;
private ArrayList<lottoCounter> madeUpArrayList;

//Constructor
lottoCounter() {
    correctLotto = 0;
    correctPlusOne = 0;
    correctPlusTwo = 0;
    number1 = 0;
    number2 = 0;
    number3 = 0;
    number4 = 0;
    number5 = 0;
    gameType = " ";
}

//setters 
public void setCorrectLotto(int correctLotto) {
    this.correctLotto = correctLotto;
}

public void setCorrectPlusOne(int correctPlusOne) {
    this.correctPlusOne = correctPlusOne;
}

public void setCorrectPlusTwo(int correctPlusTwo) {
    this.correctPlusTwo = correctPlusTwo;
}

public void setLottery(int[] lottery) {
    this.lottery = lottery;
}

public void setLotteryPlus1(int[] lotteryPlus1) {
    this.lotteryPlus1 = lotteryPlus1;
}

public void setLotteryPlus2(int[] lotteryPlus2) {
    this.lotteryPlus1 = lotteryPlus2;
}

public void setNumber1(int number1) {
    this.number1 = number1;
}

public void setNumber2(int number2) {
    this.number2 = number2;
}

public void setNumber3(int number3) {
    this.number3 = number3;
}

public void setNumber4(int number4) {
    this.number4 = number4;
}

public void setNumber5(int number5) {
    this.number5 = number5;
}

public void setGameType(String gameType) {
    this.gameType = gameType;
}

public lottoCounter(ArrayList<lottoCounter> madeUpArrayList) {
    this.madeUpArrayList = madeUpArrayList;
}

//COMPUTE
//Lottery Generator | random num generator (1-40)Lottery
public void winNums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < lottery.length; i++) {//Generating 1 to 40  numbers
        lottery[i] = (int) Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 40);//Using Math.random
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            if (lottery[i] == lottery[j]) {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    //Lottery plus 1 generator 
    for (int i = 0; i < lotteryPlus1.length; i++) {//Generating 1 to 40  numbers
        lotteryPlus1[i] = (int) Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 40);//Using Math.random
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            if (lotteryPlus1[i] == lotteryPlus1[j]) {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    //Lottery plus 2 generator 
    for (int i = 0; i < lotteryPlus2.length; i++) {//Generating 1 to 40  numbers
        lotteryPlus2[i] = (int) Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 40);//Using Math.random
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            if (lotteryPlus2[i] == lotteryPlus2[j]) {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

}


//Counter for Lottery/LotteryPlusOne/LotteryPlusTwo (COMPARISON)   
public void compareNums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            lottoCounter l;
            l = madeUpArrayList.get(i);

            if (l.getGameType().equals("lotto")) {
                if (lottery[j] == l.getNumber1() || lottery[j] == l.getNumber2() || lottery[j] == l.getNumber3() || lottery[j] == l.getNumber4() || lottery[j] == l.getNumber5()) {
                    correctLotto++;
                }
            }
            if (l.getGameType().equals("plus1")) {
                if (lotteryPlus1[j] == l.getNumber1() || lotteryPlus1[j] == l.getNumber2() || lotteryPlus1[j] == l.getNumber3() || lotteryPlus1[j] == l.getNumber4() || lotteryPlus1[j] == l.getNumber5()) {
                    correctPlusOne++;
                }
            }
            if (l.getGameType().equals("plus2")) {
                if (lotteryPlus2[j] == l.getNumber1() || lotteryPlus2[j] == l.getNumber2() || lotteryPlus2[j] == l.getNumber3() || lotteryPlus2[j] == l.getNumber4() || lotteryPlus2[j] == l.getNumber5()) {
                    correctPlusTwo++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//getters (return values to App Class)
public int getCorrectLotto() {
    return correctLotto;
}

public int getCorrectPlusOne() {
    return correctPlusOne;
}

public int getCorrectPlusTwo() {
    return correctPlusTwo;
}

public int[] getLottery() {
    return lottery;
}

public int[] getLotteryPlus1() {
    return lotteryPlus1;
}

public int[] getLotteryPlus2() {
    return lotteryPlus2;
}

public int getNumber1() {
    return number1;
}

public int getNumber2() {
    return number2;
}

public int getNumber3() {
    return number3;
}

public int getNumber4() {
    return number4;
}

public int getNumber5() {
    return number5;
}

public String getGameType() {
    return gameType;
}

public ArrayList<lottoCounter> getMadeUpArrayList() {
    return madeUpArrayList;
}
```

}

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at lottoapp.lottoCounter.compareNums(lottoCounter.java:136)
 at lottoapp.LottoApp.main(LottoApp.java:61)
C:\Users\x15587907\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)

Comment: l = madeUpArrayList.get(i);     <----- This is line 136 it is in the Instantiable class in the public void compareNums()  method

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The information you added in comments belongs in the question. I suggest moving it there.

Comment: Any idea on what to do to fix the error espertus?

Comment: I can't dig through all that code, but the NullPointerException means that madeUpArrayList is not initialized. Step through the code in a debugger to see its value before the statement that throws the exception.

Comment: Alright will try that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about anyone else but it would be nice to have more info, like the data in the arrays: `lottery`, `lotteryPlus1` and `madeUpArrayList` ect. Just to make sure that they actually have any data in them because according to your `Exception` you have a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in your method `compareNums` in line 136 of your class. Because you did not post line numbers I am not sure when the exception occurs.

I am assuming one of your arrays does not have any data in it or one or more of your arrays do not have 5 total entries of data in it because your for loop iterates 5 times. But again without seeing how or when your arrays are instantiated I do not think it is possible for anyone to confirm that is the cause of your problems. For example `lotteryPlus2[]` may only have data for `lotteryPlus2[0]`,`lotteryPlus2[1]`,and `lotteryPlus2[2]` so when `j` gets to 3 in the loop `lotteryPlus2[3]` does not exist and throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Also I am curious on why you use this for loop  `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){}`

This loop only loops once no matter what so why have it there at all since your `main method` will always run at least once anyways? Honest question, I am a beginner programmer so you may be using it for something that I have no knowledge about.

Comment: Hi i have edited my post to show the whole of the App class and Instantiable class, so the data in the arrays lottery, lotteryPlusOne, and lotteryPlusTwo is an array of 5 random numbers each in between 1 and 40 generated in the winNums() method in the Instantiable class,                              l = madeUpArrayList.get(i); <----- This is the error on line 136 it is in the Instantiable class in the public void compareNums() method                      Your right it is supposed to run multiple times but just have it running once for test purposes,   Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: for loop iterates 5 times as there is 5 numbers in each 1d array them being lottery,lotteryPlus1, and lotteryPlus2 so it is checking to see if any of these 5 numbers is the same as the user input of number1,number2,number3,number4, or number5